# Trying to read and write image as byte array in C

Tags: arrays, c, windows, file, image-processing

The following code is supposed to load and save an image file (and not only) into a copy file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* file = fopen("pexels.jpg", "r");
    if (!file) {
        perror("File opening failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long file_size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    void* data = malloc(file_size);
    memset(data, 0, file_size);
    fread(data, 1, file_size, file);
    fclose(file);

    FILE *copy = fopen("copy.jpg", "w");
    if (!copy) {
        perror("File opening failed");
        free(data);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fwrite(data, 1, file_size, copy);
    free(data);
    fclose(copy);
}
```

the file gets loaded and saved as an image using only array of bytes but the result gets corrupted.
[image]

I wonder what could be wrong here.

Comment: If you are windows add a 'b' flag  to `fopen()`.  You should check the return value of fread() and fwrite() they may not process the whole file in one go.  What's the size of the input and output file.  Please edit your questionand replace your image of your error with text.

Comment: What was the fix?  I will write up a quick answer for you.

Comment: the b flag in the fopen() function of the file that I'm trying to save solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows you need to call `fopen()` with the 'b' flag to read and write binary files.  You don't need `memset()` (and if you did, prefer `calloc()` instead).  You will probably see similar performance writing 4k or 8k at a time and eliminate the error case of running out of memory if your input file is huge.  In either case I recommend you check the return value from `fread()` and `fread()` and wrap the read/write operation in a loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* file = fopen("pexels.jpg", "br");
    if (!file) {
        perror("File opening failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long file_size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    void* data = malloc(file_size);
    fread(data, 1, file_size, file);
    fclose(file);

    FILE *copy = fopen("copy.jpg", "bw");
    if (!copy) {
        perror("File opening failed");
        free(data);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fwrite(data, 1, file_size, copy);
    free(data);
    fclose(copy);
}
```